# Find a word in file, which in some directory

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
function search_file($dir, $word){
    $result = array();
    $arr=scandir($dir);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $filename = $dir . '/' . $arr[$i];
        if(is_file($filename)){
            $x = file_get_contents($filename);

            $pos=strpos($x, $word);
            if($pos!==false){
                $result[]=$arr[$i];
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
print_r(search_file("test1", "red"));
```

This script fails to find the word **red**, though the word is present in some file in directory **test1**.  Can anyone help identify the problem?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? What is in `$x`, what is in `$pos`? Are even the files properly opened (what are `$filename`s and does `is_file(...)` return true?)

Comment: It would be better to execute a bash command from PHP, which searches for the files.

Comment: I can't do debug..how to do it in phpDesigner7 ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with phpdesigner. You debug code by printing out lines, like put `var_dump($x)` after you assign it to `$x` and see what it outputs. You do a `var_dump($word)` and see what that contains. etc. Line-by-line

Comment: I tried but anyway i got mistakes..

Comment: Warning: scandir(test1,test1): Не удается найти указанный файл. (code: 2) in C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks‌​\iskomoe_slovo.php on line 5 Call Stack: 0.0010 329112 1. {main}() C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks‌​\iskomoe_slovo.php:0 0.0010 329208 2. search_file() C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks‌​\iskomoe_slovo.php:2‌​0 0.0010 329360 3. scandir()

Comment: C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks‌​\iskomoe_slovo.php:5 Warning: scandir(test1): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks‌​\iskomoe_slovo.php on line 5 Call Stack: 0.0010 329112 1. {main}() C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks‌​\iskomoe_slovo.php:0 0.0010 329208 2. search_file() C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks‌​\iskomoe_slovo.php:2‌​0

Comment: just ran your code and it worked for me. make sure you're specifying the complete path, not just "test1" but something like '/var/www/html/test1"

Comment: Yes! Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to work just fine. The only thing is to make sure you're using a complete path, so change:

```
print_r(search_file("test1", "red"));
```

To something like:

```
print_r(search_file("/var/www/html/test1", "red"));
```